# Where can I find information on how to develop for Opera Unite? [close]

Tags: opera

[Opera Unite](http://unite.opera.com/) (a web browser that can act as a server) has just been released and they claim that you can build web services so other people can access your browser. I'm interested in making a program for the platform.

Can someone point me to a site on how to develop for Opera Unite?

---

Close: nevermind, the page I linked to has a link to a [developer's guide](http://dev.opera.com/articles/unite/). Silly me, but it wasn't there when I saw the link at reddit.

Comment: Kudos on being the first to ask an opera-unite question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just to have the question not showing anymore in the unanswered list ;)

- The official site for [Opera Unite](http://unite.opera.com/applications/)
- The [developer Guide for Opera Unite](http://unite.opera.com/develop/)
- The [primer for developers](http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/opera-unite-developer-primer-revisited/) will guide people through the steps.
- There is also the important [Unite API Library](http://dev.opera.com/libraries/unite/)
- There is a forum about [Opera Unite](http://my.opera.com/community/forums/forum.dml?id=15515) to help with questions.